# Is there a function to set two mouse buttons to activate a script?

Tags: lua, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

I'm working on a recoil script, and I want to be able to activate it using left- and right-click.
This is what I have so far. I want to use mb1 and mb2 to make it work, not just mb1.

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
  OutputLogMessage("event = %s, arg = %d\n", event, arg)
  if (event == "PROFILE_ACTIVATED") then
    EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
  elseif event == "PROFILE_DEACTIVATED" then
    ReleaseMouseButton(2) -- to prevent it from being stuck on
  end
  if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 4) then
    recoil = not recoil
    spot = not spot
  end
  if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 and recoil) then
    if recoil then
      repeat
        MoveMouseRelative(-2, 5)
        Sleep(10)
        MoveMouseRelative(2, -5)
        Sleep(21)
      until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Do you want to set an event handler for SIMULTANEOUS press of both mouse buttons?

Comment: yes, so basically i need to ads and shoot to make it work once i stop shooting then it stops working. @EgorSkriptunoff